# Error during test does not show up on real compile and tests won't run

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

My first Angular 5 app...

I'm setting up a Jasmine test according to: https://angular.io/guide/testing and as soon as it starts, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/pizzaplace.service.spec.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/thomas/git/pizza-cloud-site/pizza-cloud-admin/src/app/pizzaplace.service"' has no exported member 'PizzaplaceService'.
```

This error does not show up when I do a regular compile. Here is the code in question in pizzaplace.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class PizzaPlaceService {
    //class stuff
}
```

And the tests fail to connect to Chrome like:

```
27 02 2018 04:40:38.935:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
27 02 2018 04:40:38.941:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
27 02 2018 04:40:38.941:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
27 02 2018 04:40:38.964:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
27 02 2018 04:41:38.966:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
27 02 2018 04:41:39.286:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
27 02 2018 04:42:39.286:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
27 02 2018 04:42:39.513:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
27 02 2018 04:43:39.514:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
27 02 2018 04:43:39.693:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

The Chrome browser opens and tries to point at: http://localhost:9876/?id=98768812 but it is never able to resolve it.

Which, I'm assuming has something to do with the error. I googled the error message and it returned unrelated things.

Here is my unit test:

```
describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

Comment: The two error is not the same. The first one is I think gives error because of the path. The second error is that karma couldn't open your browser. `No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/`
Also you should include your test file pizzaplace.service.spec.ts

Comment: @ZoltánBedi I have clarified the question. I hadn't posted the unit test because I didn't think it useful, but I've added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you are trying to load:

```
PizzaplaceService
```

But the class is named:

```
PizzaPlaceService 
     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second part of the question about "Chrome have not captured in 60000ms" (and for anyone else who has been driven mad by the error).

To fix this I had to add the option `'--no-sandbox'` to the chrome flags part of my Karma.conf.js and as a chrome args in my protractor.conf.js file file as chrome didn't seem to be running with enough security.  Browsing with chrome in this way is heavily frowned on as it isn't safe but given that the browser starts and ends completely under automation with extensions off I consider it a low risk.

I am now using headless chrome but the same issue occurred with just chrome too.

My Karma conf now looks like:

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
singleRun: true,
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadless: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: [
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-translate',
      '--disable-extensions',
      '--no-sandbox',  // Added to fix an issue where of Failed to connect to chrome browser
     '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
    ],
  }
}
```

My protractor.conf.js file now contains:-

  `capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
      binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
      args: ['--no-sandbox']
    }`

Hope that helps :-)